# Comparing two virtually identical BigDecimal numbers in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, precision, equality, bigdecimal

I got a little problem that I really would like to understand. I am using `assert_equal` to compare two BigDecimal numbers that are supposed to be identical. They actually are except a very little tiny fraction, see below:

```
-#<BigDecimal:7f4b40e8de78,'0.4021666666 6666666666 666666667E2',36(45)>
+#<BigDecimal:7f4b40e85db8,'0.4021666666 6666666666 6666668E2',36(63)>
```

I use `assert_in_delta` in order to not fail the test cases. So I got a reasonable *workaround*. I do wonder though whether it would be possible to have it equal:

```
assert_equal (241.30.to_d/6), model.division_function
```

The *model*'s `division_function` does exactly the same. It divides a BigDecimal of value `241.3` by the length of an array, which is `6`.

There seems to be a very tiny difference in the precision.
I would like to know where that might come from?
Is there a way I can control precision more accurately?

**EDIT**
I am using Mongoid. It is worth to note that Mongoid offers BigDecimal as a field type, but it is stored as a string. However, I don't think this is the problem. I believe it is a Ruby thing.

**EDIT**
I got a little further with an example which hints that it is a Ruby issue and not directly related to Rails. Please see below:

```
irb(main):041:0* amount1 = BigDecimal("241.3")
=> #<BigDecimal:7f49bcb03558,'0.2413E3',18(18)>
irb(main):042:0> amount2 = BigDecimal("1800")
=> #<BigDecimal:7f49bcaf3400,'0.18E4',9(18)>
irb(main):043:0> rate = amount1 / amount2
=> #<BigDecimal:7f49bcae8398,'0.1340555555 5555555555 5555556E0',27(45)>
irb(main):044:0> rate * amount2 #should return amount1 = 241.3, but it does not :-(
=> #<BigDecimal:7f49bcad6a30,'0.2413000000 0000000000 00000008E3',36(45)>
irb(main):045:0>
```

Comment: You could do the math using methods from the [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Rational.html) class.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post the division_function is simply doing a division of two attributes the same way as the first argument in the `assert_equal` method call. One field is BigDecimal and another one is an integer size of an array.

I will try to come up with a simple example.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks for the hint. Did not know about that. Good to know.

However I rely on BigDecimal as Rational unfortunately is not a supported data type in the Rails framework. So in this particular case I cannot use Rational.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a bug and the answer does not help solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reported the [bug](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10850) to the Ruby core team. However, this is not a bug as you can see in the rejection response.

[BigDecimal](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/BigDecimal.html), though offers arbitrary precision, cannot represent numbers like 1/3 precisely. Thus during some arithmetic you can encounter imprecisions.

You can use [Rational](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Rational.html) in Ruby for exact numbers. Exercise caution when doing arithmetics if you wish to keep the result exact.